# Change field value of priority-queue object?

Tags: java, priority-queue

I have a bank teller simulation program I am writing, using a PriorityQueue(PQ) full of objects of the class type Customer, which has a field priorityNum.  When a customer leaves the queue, I need to increment the priorityNum of customers still in the queue.

My question being: How can I go through a PQ and increment a field for the objects?

Comment: Why would you increment the priority number?

Comment: As the customer "shows up" they are given a priority number from 1 - 10.  The longer they are waiting to be serviced, the higher their priority gets.  I'm pulling the highest priority customers out of the queue first.

Comment: Ah I see, makes sense now.

Comment: I don't think that it would make sense to create a priority queue for this, since a Priority Queue actually sorts the queue every time you update an element. If you would create a LinkedList, you could specify when it should sort the list. Notice: LinkedList has the same nice operations such as `remove()` and `add()`. You can use the `Collections.sort()` to sort the LinkedList. With this construction you can use a simple for-loop and update all the elements. This would save you in the runtime and would probably make the implementation a lot easier.

Comment: True, it would be much easier with a LinkedList.  Unfortunately, the parameters I am creating this program under require I use a priority queue. Thanks for the advice though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do a `for each` type iteration, you can go through `PriorityQueue<Customer>` using

```
for (Customer c : queue) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Iterator to iterate over a queue.

```
Iterator<Customer> iterator=queue.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext())
{
    Customer c=iterator.next();
 }
```